# verilog programmer about for loop

Tags: for-loop, verilog

```
always @* begin
for (i = 0; i < 256; i = i + 1) begin
    for (j = 0; j < 256; j = j + 1) begin
       if (image_data[i] == image_data[j]) begin
       pattern_counts[i] = pattern_counts[i] + 1;
    end
end
end
end
```

like this , why the  pattern_counts =  pattern_counts +1  will not creat the Combinational logic loop and why this is Synthesizable

please help tell the detail about the Verilog , how it works for this

Comment: it will as soon as you initialize *pattern_counts* and *image_data*. There will be no loop if its value is 'x'.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize `pattern_counts`. You probable ant to do something like:

```
always @* begin
  for (i = 0; i < 256; i = i + 1) begin
    pattern_counts[i] = 0 ; //   <---   INITIALIZE
    for (j = 0; j < 256; j = j + 1) begin
      if (image_data[i] == image_data[j]) begin
        pattern_counts[i] = pattern_counts[i] + 1;
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Without initialize `pattern_counts` the value is `x`(unknown) and `x+1` is still `x`.
If your synthesizer is accepting your original logic, it is likely optimizing out the code.